# How do I share a variable among multiple methods?

Tags: java, android

after saved instance I need share "int audio" to check() method to do several operations. I've an "info" option: when I click I see info dialog and I'd like listen audio (stop it when I click on "cancel"). But when I rotate emulator, I've another audio stars.

```
int audio;
static int Info;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
int Info = savedInstanceState.getInt("dialoginfo");
int audio = savedInstanceState.getInt("audio");
}

if(Info != 0)
  {
      Info();
}

private void Info(){
    Info = 1;
    sobCheck();
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View view = li.inflate(R.layout.info, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(view).create();
    TextView text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoView1);
    builder.setCancelable(false); 
    builder.setPositiveButton("Chiudi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
               Info = 0;
               mp.stop();
               mp.reset();
               mp.release();
                mp = null;
                audio = 0;                  
               dialog.cancel();
        }  
        });  
    builder.show();
        }


private void sobCheck(){
if (audio == 0){
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sob);
mp.start();
audio = 1;
}



protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putInt("audio", a);
```

after rotate screen, "audio" is always "0"

Comment: Please note the Java naming conventions: variable names start with a lower case letter. So, `static int info;` instead of `static int Info;`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've created locally scoped variables that shadow your application level variables here:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        int Info = savedInstanceState.getInt("dialoginfo");
        int audio = savedInstanceState.getInt("audio");
    }

    if (Info != 0) {
        Info();
    }
}
```

This declares and initializes two **new** variables *Info* and *audio* that are scoped to your if check and discarded immediately after. They do not actually change the application level variables you declared outside the onCreate method. Try changing it to this:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Info = savedInstanceState.getInt("dialoginfo");
        audio = savedInstanceState.getInt("audio");
    }

    if (Info != 0) {
        Info();
    }
}
```

This prevents *Info* and *audio* from being redeclared in your local scope and should instead result in your already declared variables being initialized.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare it outside onCreate() scope:

```
int audio;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        audio = savedInstanceState.getInt("audio");
}
```

Comment: in the check() method, "audio" is always 0

Comment: `audio = 1;` will never run. It won't even compile. You have to set it somewhere else. You can only set values in the scope immediately above your class if you're declaring it, like `int audio = 1`. After declaration, you can only set values for variables inside methods.

Answer (score 0):

you re-initialize "audio" inside the method. just take out the "int" before you assign the value of audio.

Comment: if I put mediaplayer outside method I've a crash of my app

Comment: and "audio" is always different from 1 when subCheck() is runs